# Como fazer com que a propriedade clip:rect(...) não ocupe espaço (width)

Tags: html5, css3

Gostava de saber se há alguma hipótese do `clip: rect(...)` realmente 'cortar' o elemento em questão, não o ocultando apenas.

Aqui nesta imagem, sem o `clip: rect(...)`, mostra o borda a exceder o espaço do seu container (caixa branca) e consequentemente o scroll horizontal aparece.

[image: sem clip]

Nesta vemos a mesma coisa mas com o `clip: rect(...)`, e não vemos nada a exceder o container, apenas o seu 'vazio'. O que influencia também a scroll horizontal.

[image: com clip]

Todo o conteúdo é ajustável á largura do ecrã, se eu aumentar ou diminuir a largura da janela, o scroll horizontal manté-se igual.

Resumidamente, gostava de saber de uma solução para essa borda não ocupar aquele espacinho a mais.

Comment: Você não poderia usar dimensões absolutas no border-radius, e reduzir o container?

Comment: Poderia disponibilizar um exemplo em um site como jsfiddle.com ou jsbin.com? Eu iria sugerir que usa `margin-right: -12px /*algum número*/`, mas não sei se iria funcionar.

Comment: Só uma pergunta: Você usa algum framework (bootstrap ou similar)?

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, @bfavaretto! Eu não pretendo reduzir o container, ele vai ser sempre da largura da página. Ajusta-se.
@GustavoRodrigues, eu resolvi a situação aumentando as margens laterais do `(...) li p`
Mas mesmo assim procurava uma solução mais razoável, uma vez que esta altera um pouco layout desejável, pois os balões afastam-se das laterais.
@EdgarMunizBerlinck, não estou a usar nenhum framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta inserir `overflow-x:hidden;` nos elementos `.chat` e/ou `ul.messages` assim independente do elemento ultrapassar ou não o limite a barra de rolagem horizontal não vai ser mostrada.

```
.char, .chat ul.messages {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Erlon! Não funciona porque aquele scroll horizontal é da página e não apenas do elemento. De qualquer forma, preferia uma solução mais direcionada ao elemento...

Comment: Mas com isso você removeria a influencia do elemento sobre o scroll da página. Teria como reproduzir o comportamento no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Funcionou! Como não estava a perceber a lógica pensei que não ia resultar, mas acabei agora de testar e realmente é isto que procurava! Pode-me explicar um pouco como funciona? Porque `overflow-x: hidden` serve para remover o scroll horizontal, e como não chegou a aparecer um scroll não relacionei...

Comment: [Aqui](http://campus.tableless.com.br/2012/05/propriedade-overflow/) você pode ver uma rápida vídeo aula sobre esta propriedade.

Comment: Agora percebi como a propriedade `overflow` realmente funciona! Eu compreendia-a como uma propriedade que trancasse o scroll (ocultando-o neste caso) e não como uma propriedade que oculta o conteúdo mesmo. "overflow" em inglês realmente quer dizer isso, eu é que raramente uso essa propriedade que nem sabia ao certo o que fazia :D
Muito obrigado ;)